# Which flow should I choose for OAuth authorization with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

OAuth 2.0 authorization server has authorization grant flows for applications. For a token request there are 3 options:

- Authorization Code Flow
- Implicit Flow
- Resource Owner Credentials Flow

Which should I use in an Angular JavaScript application? Authorization Code and Implicit flow require Client Secret information. And Resource Owner credentials needs username and password. I am confused a bit.

Comment: I understand that if you implement oauth purely on front-end, you should use implicit

Comment: Does not importent client secret of my applicaiton?